# Azure CI Pipeline failing at build stage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

My Azure CI Pipeline is failing at the Build stage. It is a standard template pipeline for a TFVC repo and a ASP.net web application.

Please note that the application builds successfully in Visual Studio 2015. I have not tried with any other version (Does that make a difference?)

The error message says that

> The type or namespace cannot be found. Are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?

I have checked and the reference exists in the project file.

Comment: the logs in the pipeline should tell you exactly what type can't be resolved. maybe you are using a .net-dll that is not on the build-server ?

Comment: [Microsoft-hosted vs2017-win2016 agent](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2016-Readme.md) use Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 and [Microsoft-hosted windows-2019 agent](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) uses Visual Studio Enterprise 2019, please check if project works with this newer Visual Studio version, and then use these hosted agents in pipeline to build your project. In addition, set variable system.debug in true in pipeline can get debug logs to help you troubleshoot pipeline issues.

Comment: Hi, How about this issue? If it is resolved, could you please share your solution here, which can guide others who might encounter this issue in the future? Thank you very much.